# PHP и ISPMGR API. Ошибка в редактировании зоны

Tags: php, isp

В общем ломаю голову над такой штукой. Пытаюсь поменять ip и dns домена. Далее мой код

```
php 
<? 
$hid_user='имя';
$hid_pass='пасс';

$url = "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']."/manager/ispmgr?authinfo=".$hid_user.":".$hid_pass."&out=xml&func=dom ain.edit";

$add_domaindns["elid"] = "имя_моего_домена";
$add_domaindns["sok"] = "yes";
$add_domaindns["reversezone"] = "on";

$add_domaindns["ip"] = "46.31.211.191";

foreach( $add_domaindns as $k => $v )
{
$url .= '&'.$k.'='.urlencode($v);
}

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $response;

?>
```

При выполнении получаю ответ
An error occurred while editing the имя_домена zone . The file might have been damaged имя:пасс имя_домена domain.edit 46.31.211.191 xml on yes
А вот теперь ПОМОГИТЕ ПОЖАЛУЙСТА)))))